# Refactor to module creates different type request from compiler?

Tags: types, rust, image-resizing

Why I am getting a compiler request for different types when refactoring this [example code](https://github.com/PistonDevelopers/resize/blob/master/examples/resize.rs) to use a wrapper around the [resize](https://github.com/PistonDevelopers/resize) image library.

Basically resize always seems to be `u16` output so why is my change asking for `u8` when the original code never required this conversion?

```
extern crate resize;

use resize::Type;
use resize::Pixel;

pub struct Resize{
    w1:usize,
    h1:usize,
    w2:usize,
    h2:usize,
    src: Vec<u16>,
}

impl Resize {
    pub fn new(
        ow:usize, 
        oh:usize, 
        dw:usize, 
        dh:usize,
        inc: Vec<u16>
    ) -> Resize {
        Resize {
            w1:ow,
            h1:oh,
            w2:dw,
            h2:dh,
            src:inc,
        }
    }

    pub fn run(&self) -> Vec<u16> {
        let mut dst = vec![0;self.w2*self.h2];
        resize::resize(
            self.w1, 
            self.h1, 
            self.w2, 
            self.h2, 
            Pixel::RGBA64, 
            Type::Lanczos3, 
            self.src.as_slice(), 
            &mut dst,
        );
        dst
    }
}
```

**Compiler error message**

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:24:45
   |
24 |     let image = Resize::new(w1, h1, w2, h2, src);
   |                                             ^^^ expected u16, found u8
   |
   = note: expected type `std::vec::Vec<u16>`
              found type `std::vec::Vec<u8>`
   = help: here are some functions which might fulfill your needs:
           - .to_vec()

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:30:54
   |
30 |     encoder.write_header().unwrap().write_image_data(dst).unwrap();
   |                                                      ^^^ expected u8, found u16
   |
   = note: expected type `&[u8]`
              found type `&[u16]`
```

Comment: Please provide a more accurate [MCVE]. Your question should enable us to reproduce the problem without visiting external links or inferring unmentioned API usage. In particular, where is the code that includes the line `let image = Resize::new(w1, h1, w2, h2, src);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR: Expected type of `src` variable is `Vec<u16>`, but it's set to `Vec<u8>`, because of type inference.**

---

Variable `src` is assigned in line:

```
let mut src = vec![0;info.buffer_size()];
```

It infers the type as `Vec<u8>` later by calling:

```
reader.next_frame(&mut src).unwrap();
```

or

```
resize::resize(w1, h1, w2, h2, Gray8, Triangle, &src, &mut dst);
```

Because those functions expect type `&mut [u8]`, not `&mut [u16]`.

If we set expected type `Vec<u16>` explicitly when assigning `src`:

```
let mut src: Vec<u16> = vec![0; info.buffer_size()];
```

Now calling `next_frame()` and `resize()` will fail because types not match, but compiler will give us better hints what's wrong and what can we do about it.

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:65:23
   |
65 |     reader.next_frame(&mut src).unwrap();
   |                       ^^^^^^^^ expected slice, found struct `std::vec::Vec`
   |
   = note: expected type `&mut [u8]`
              found type `&mut std::vec::Vec<u16>`
   = help: here are some functions which might fulfill your needs:
           - .as_mut_slice()

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:74:53
   |
74 |     resize::resize(w1, h1, w2, h2, Gray8, Triangle, &src, &mut dst);
   |                                                     ^^^^ expected slice, found struct `std::vec::Vec`
   |
   = note: expected type `&[u8]`
              found type `&std::vec::Vec<u16>`
   = help: here are some functions which might fulfill your needs:
           - .as_slice()
```